# Dispose all GDI objects from third party ActiveX control wrapper 

Tags: c#, activex, gdi, dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

I have created a C# ActiveX control wrapper than I am using to wrap a third party ActiveX control.

I have the ActiveX control wrapper registered and I can add it to a form in Dynamics AX.  When I open the form ~400 GDI objects are created each time.  However the problem I have is that when the AX form is closed, none of the GDI objects are released.

Eventually I get the following error inside AX.

[image]

I have methods that in my C# wrapper that I can call into from the Wrap I created where I am explicitly calling Dispose on the third party control.  However that only cleans up around half of the GDI objects created (~200/400)

So the problem is everytime the AX form is opened and closed around ~200 new GDI objects are created.

What else can I be looking at to get rid of the rest of the GDI objects created (or nearly all of them?)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, and a hotfix is available for that. This however is an issue with 2009 SP1.
Follow this discussion on the dynamics forums: http://community.dynamics.com/product/ax/f/33/p/30936/52754.aspx
A link is available in the KB for this hotfix

Filtering of the Grid is one of the issues of this, but will be good to check it.